# Convert date time with AM PM to 24 hour date format

Tags: php, datetime-format

How to convert `10/25/2014 14:00 PM` to `2014-10-25 14:00:00` in php?

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("10/25/2014 14:00 PM"));
```

returns

```
1970-01-01 03:00:00
```

Comment: `10/25/2014 14:00 PM` is valid because in `am/pm` format only `12 hours` applicable

Comment: how would i convert the above m/d/Y H:i A format to required Y/m/d H:i:s format ?

Comment: is the date have 24 hours representation with am/pm?

Comment: the format is wrong. you have to do it manually.or just replace `AM/PM`

Comment: @neeraj did you double checked the accepted answer with `AM` values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the origin of that date is (how it came to that), but you can use `DateTime` classes for this:

```
$raw_date = '10/25/2014 14:00 PM';
// to disregard that PM escape it in the format
$new_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y H:i \P\M', $raw_date);
echo $new_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2014-10-25 14:00:00
```

Comment: what happen if `$raw_date = '10/25/2014 10:00 AM';` or `$raw_date = '10/25/2014 10:00 am';` or `$raw_date = '10/25/2014 14:00 pm';`

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = "10/25/2014 14:00 PM"; //Here is the date 24 hours format with am/pm
$date = substr($date, 0, -2); //Removed the am/pm from date


echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date)); //then convert it to mysql date format
```

Note: 
   If you use this for date column means replace it data type to int and save unix time stamp which have more comfortable if year limited to 1970 to year 2038.
For reason not to use more than 2038 [read here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)

Comment: That means there is no inbuilt function in php to achieve that. i will have to apply this hack?

Comment: Not like that your format is not universally used format so no direct function

Answer (score 1):

> 10/25/2014 14:00 PM your input date format is not correct, you are using 12hr format so time will be 10/25/2014 02:00 PM